# .NET4: In-Process Side-by-Side Execution Explained

Tags: c#, .net, process, assemblies, .net-4.0

**Overview**: I'm interested in learning more about the .NET4 "In-Process Side-by-Side Execution" of assemblies, and need additional information to help me demystify it.

**Motivation**: The application in question is built against .NET2, and uses two third-party libraries that also work against .NET2.  The application is deployed (via file copy) to client machines in a virtual environment that includes .NET2.  *Not my architecture, please bear with me.*

**Goal**: To see if it's possible to rebuild the application assemblies (or a subset) against .NET4, and ship the application as before, without changing the third-party libraries and including the .NET4 Client Profile (as described [here](http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/)) in the deployment.

**Steps Taken**: The following articles were read, but didn't quite provide me enough information:

1. [In-Process Side-by-Side Execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee518876.aspx): Browsed this article, and Scenario Two is the closest it comes to describing something that resembles my situation, but doesn't really cover it with any depth.
2. [ASP.NET Side-by-Side Execution Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a99txfy5.aspx): This article covers a web application, but I'm dealing with a client WinForms application.
3. [CLR Team Blog: In-Process Side-by-Side](http://blogs.msdn.com/clrteam/archive/2009/06/03/in-process-side-by-side-part1.aspx): This is useful to explain how plug-ins to host processes function under .NET4, but I don't know if this applies to the third-party libraries.

**Further Steps**: I'm also unclear on how to proceed upgrading a single .NET2 assembly to .NET4, with the executable remaining in .NET2 (i.e. how to configure the solution/project files, if any special code needs to be included, etc.).

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but have you just tried running the application as-is in the .NET 4 CLR? Do you *know* that the third party assemblies won't work (e.g. due to mixed-mode code)? I'd try to get everything running under .NET 4 before going side-by-side.

Comment: Ignore previous comment.  From what I understand (and I'm fuzzy on this as well), the virtual environment (ThinApp) ships some kind of .NET2 redistributable, and the third-party library (Crystal Reports) works against that.  So, no, haven't gotten a chance yet but currently working on it - I'd like to know what I'm getting into.

I think it is a pain to upgrade in-place the ThinApp clients, but *I think* we can distribute .NET Client Profile via file copy without as many hitches.

Comment: Can you define "overall application"?  Do you mean the EXE assembly?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can load assemblies created against .NET 2 in the .NET 4 runtime.  So you should try this first and see if it "just works".  Just covert your app to VS 2010 / .NET 4, and try to compile it with the same references to the third party assemblies.  Then deploy and it will probably work.